# Integration of Oracle DB or APEX with Abinitio

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c, ab-initio

How to integrate Oracle DB/APEX with abinitio.

Scenario : I have a Abinitio code which generates the monthly report. So being database developer i wants to run same code which is in abinitio and generates monthly report. So i am looking for any connector between Abinitio and oracle DB / APEX.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Plz read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to post question.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate Oracle with another database you have different options

1. JDBC (you have to develop this function in JAVA as ETL) (Use a software like Talend or another ETL)
2. Oracle Link Database (You have to ask your DBA if it's possible)
3. Expose the info in JSON and make a web service call (Develop a web service in java, node, python, as so on) and consume the json exposed.

If I were you, I would use the option number 3 because It's cleaner option.

If you need more info let me know asap.

Answer (score 0):

0. Preliminary step: make sure that JDBC drivers is installer and accessible
1. create DBC file for specify connection to Oracle DBMS.
2. use `m_db` for generate DBC template and also for test connection from Shell or GDE